# Using group_concat mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables `jeans`and `bahanbenang` and I want to use `group_concat` to concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field.
This is my SQL code:

```
SELECT jeans.id_jeans, jeans.id_benang, GROUP_CONCAT( bahanbenang.warna
SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS warna, GROUP_CONCAT( bahanbenang.jenis
SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS jenis
FROM jeans
LEFT JOIN bahanbenang ON jeans.id_benang = bahanbenang.id_benang
GROUP BY jeans.id_jeans
```

giving the following result:

[image: result]

My main question is why can't the resulting query return more than one value in columns `warna` and `jenis`?

I want the result to be like this:

[image: table bahanbenang]

*update
Iam trying following thi query

```
SELECT 
jeans.id_jeans, jeans.id_benang, 
GROUP_CONCAT( bahanbenang.warna SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS warna, 
GROUP_CONCAT( bahanbenang.jenis SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS jenis
 FROM jeans
LEFT JOIN bahanbenang ON FIND_IN_SET(bahanbenang.id_benang, jeans.id_benang) = 1
GROUP BY jeans.id_benang
```

but the result same

[image]

Comment: Storing list of ids in a single column is a bad, bad, bad idea.  The ids are numbers and numbers should not be stored as strings.  Ids should have foreign key relationships, and multiple values in a string cannot have a foreign key relationship.  Any resulting query on the ids cannot make use of an index.  Restructure your data to use junction tables.

Answer (score 0):

The JOIN condition should be improved. Try the following query.

```
SELECT 
    jeans.id_jeans, jeans.id_benang, 
    GROUP_CONCAT( bahanbenang.warna SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS warna, 
    GROUP_CONCAT( bahanbenang.jenis SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS jenis
FROM jeans
LEFT JOIN bahanbenang ON FIND_IN_SET(bahanbenang.id_benang, jeans.id_benang) = 1
GROUP BY jeans.id_benang
```

Comment: I'am trying to use your query but the result same